# TableView not displaying items correctly

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I want my TableView with my three TableColumns to display some products in it.
Upon adding new Products they are saved in the data containers, but are not shown in my Table View

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellEditEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
public class ViewShop extends BorderPane {

    private Button add;
    private Button remove;
    private TextField name;
    private TextField price;
    private TextField count;
    private VBox vbox;
    private HBox hbox;
    public TableView<fpt.com.Product> tv;
    private TableColumn<fpt.com.Product, Number> sprice;
    private TableColumn<fpt.com.Product, String> sname;
    private TableColumn <fpt.com.Product, Number>scount;
    private Label namelabel;
    private Label pricelabel;
    private Label countlabel;

    private ListView<fpt.com.Product> list; 

    public ViewShop()
    {

        remove=new Button("Remove");
        add=new Button("Add");
        name=new TextField();
        price=new TextField();
        count=new TextField();
        tv=new TableView<fpt.com.Product>();
        sprice=new TableColumn<fpt.com.Product, Number>("Preis");
        sname=new TableColumn<fpt.com.Product, String>("Name");
        scount=new TableColumn<fpt.com.Product, Number>("Anzahl");
        namelabel=new Label("Name");
        pricelabel=new Label("Preis");
        countlabel=new Label("Anzahl");
        list = new ListView<fpt.com.Product>();
        hbox=new HBox();
        vbox=new VBox();
        tv.getColumns().addAll(sname,sprice,scount);
        tv.setEditable(true);
        tv.getColumns().get(0).getCellData(0);
        tv.setItems(list.getItems());
        sname.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
        sprice.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceProperty());
        scount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty());
        tv.setItems(list.getItems());
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(remove, add);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(namelabel,name,pricelabel ,price, countlabel , count, hbox);
        this.setRight(vbox);
        this.setLeft(tv);
    }
    public void addEventHandleradd(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
        this.add.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, eventHandler);
    }
    public void addEventHandlerremove(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eventHandler) {
        this.remove.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, eventHandler);
    }
    public String giveName()
    {
        return name.getText();
    }
    public String givePrice()
    {
        return price.getText();
    }
    public String giveCount()
    {
        return count.getText();
    }
    public ListView<fpt.com.Product> getList()
    {
        return list;
    }


}
```

Class ControllerShop

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;

public class ControllerShop {

    ModelShop model;
    ViewShop view;

    public void link(ModelShop model, ViewShop view)
    {
        this.model=model;
        this.view=view;
        model.setProductList();
        view.getList().setItems(model);
        view.addEventHandleradd(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                model.doAdd(model.size(), new Product(view.giveName(), Integer.parseInt(view.giveCount()), Double.parseDouble(view.givePrice())));
                System.out.println(view.getList().getItems().size());
                System.out.println(model.size());
            }
        });
        view.addEventHandlerremove(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                model.remove(model.findProductByName(view.giveName()));
                }
        });

    }

}
```

Class Product

```
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;

public class Product implements fpt.com.Product {

    Long id;
    SimpleStringProperty name;
    SimpleIntegerProperty quantity;
    SimpleDoubleProperty price;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, double price)
    {
        this.name=new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.quantity=new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.price=new SimpleDoubleProperty(price);
    }




    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id=id;

    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    @Override
    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    @Override
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public DoubleProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public IntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity;
    }

}
```

Class Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        ModelShop model=new ModelShop();
        ViewShop view=new ViewShop();
        ControllerShop controller=new ControllerShop();
        controller.link(model, view);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(view, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewShop` constructor you set the items list of the table to the items list of the `ListView`:

```
tv.setItems(list.getItems());
```

Then, later, in the constructor for your controller, you change the items list of the `ListView` to be the list from the model:

```
view.getList().setItems(model);
```

However, you don't change the items list of the table at this point. So now the `ListView`'s items list is the model, but the table's items list is the original (default) items list from the `ListView`. Hence when you add things to your model, the table will not see those items.

You either need to set the items list of the table to the model in the controller constructor:

```
view.getTable().setItems(model);
```

(with an obvious `getTable()` method defined in the view), or you can bind the table's items to the list's items, by replacing

```
tv.setItems(list.getItems());
```

with

```
tv.itemsProperty().bind(list.itemsProperty());
```

in the view constructor.

Comment: The method setitems(ObservableList<Product> value )                                                     of TableView  expects an ObservableList. So the TableView is notified when its items are changed. I believe that this is the reason for your proposal not working out. I tested it and it did not. But still thank you for your proposal :) Can you see any other reasons why the code is not working?

Comment: I assumed `model` was an `ObservableList<Product>` since you are also passing it to the list view's `setItems` method.

Comment: Also, if you need more of a solution than I have provided, I recommend you create a [MCVE]. My solution works just fine in my test case.

Comment: I fixed the problem with a very strange solution. I added those lines into the ControllerShip:

Comment: `int i=0; ` I declared this new variable outside the method.
 I added the following code in the method handle, i turned tv to a public variable in ViewShop   `i++;
    view.tv.getItems().add(new Product("a",1,1));
    view.tv.getItems().remove(i); `, now it is working. But I really don't know why -.-